# How to modify the layout in Joomla articles?

Tags: php, templates, joomla

On a Joomla 3.4 site, articles display a "details" section like this by default :

*Details*

*Written by John Doe*

*Published: 26 October 2015*

What file to change, (and if possible how) to get the following result ?

*By John Doe, on November 4, 2015*

---

Edit after @itoctopus answer :

> you will need to change the override file. You can do that by changing the
>   file /templates/your-template/html/com_content/article/default.php

Below is the content of the default.php.

What should be changed to achieve the result above ? I see nothing in this file related to the "details" section.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_content
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers');

// Create shortcuts to some parameters.
$params  = $this->item->params;
$images  = json_decode($this->item->images);
$urls    = json_decode($this->item->urls);
$canEdit = $params->get('access-edit');
$user    = JFactory::getUser();
$info    = $params->get('info_block_position', 0);
JHtml::_('behavior.caption');
?>
<div class="item-page<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx; ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <meta itemprop="inLanguage" content="<?php echo ($this->item->language === '*') ? JFactory::getConfig()->get('language') : $this->item->language; ?>" />
    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading')) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?> </h1>
    </div>
    <?php endif;
    if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && !$this->item->paginationposition && $this->item->paginationrelative)
    {
        echo $this->item->pagination;
    }
    ?>

    <?php // Todo Not that elegant would be nice to group the params ?>
    <?php $useDefList = ($params->get('show_modify_date') || $params->get('show_publish_date') || $params->get('show_create_date')
    || $params->get('show_hits') || $params->get('show_category') || $params->get('show_parent_category') || $params->get('show_author') ); ?>

    <?php if (!$useDefList && $this->print) : ?>
        <div id="pop-print" class="btn hidden-print">
            <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_screen', $this->item, $params); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('show_title') || $params->get('show_author')) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2 itemprop="name">
            <?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
                <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </h2>
        <?php if ($this->item->state == 0) : ?>
            <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo JText::_('JUNPUBLISHED'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (strtotime($this->item->publish_up) > strtotime(JFactory::getDate())) : ?>
            <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo JText::_('JNOTPUBLISHEDYET'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ((strtotime($this->item->publish_down) < strtotime(JFactory::getDate())) && $this->item->publish_down != JFactory::getDbo()->getNullDate()) : ?>
            <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo JText::_('JEXPIRED'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (!$this->print) : ?>
        <?php if ($canEdit || $params->get('show_print_icon') || $params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
            <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.icons', array('params' => $params, 'item' => $this->item, 'print' => false)); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php if ($useDefList) : ?>
            <div id="pop-print" class="btn hidden-print">
                <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_screen', $this->item, $params); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($useDefList && ($info == 0 || $info == 2)) : ?>
        <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.block', array('item' => $this->item, 'params' => $params, 'position' => 'above')); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($info == 0 && $params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($this->item->tags->itemTags)) : ?>
        <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>

        <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (!$params->get('show_intro')) : echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayTitle; endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>

    <?php if (isset($urls) && ((!empty($urls->urls_position) && ($urls->urls_position == '0')) || ($params->get('urls_position') == '0' && empty($urls->urls_position)))
        || (empty($urls->urls_position) && (!$params->get('urls_position')))) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('links'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('access-view')):?>
    <?php if (isset($images->image_fulltext) && !empty($images->image_fulltext)) : ?>
    <?php $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_fulltext)) ? $params->get('float_fulltext') : $images->float_fulltext; ?>
    <div class="pull-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?> item-image"> <img
    <?php if ($images->image_fulltext_caption):
        echo 'class="caption"' . ' title="' . htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_caption) . '"';
    endif; ?>
    src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_alt); ?>" itemprop="image"/> </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && !$this->item->paginationposition && !$this->item->paginationrelative):
        echo $this->item->pagination;
    endif;
    ?>
    <?php if (isset ($this->item->toc)) :
        echo $this->item->toc;
    endif; ?>
    <div itemprop="articleBody">
        <?php echo $this->item->text; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($useDefList && ($info == 1 || $info == 2)) : ?>
        <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.block', array('item' => $this->item, 'params' => $params, 'position' => 'below')); ?>
        <?php if ($params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($this->item->tags->itemTags)) : ?>
            <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && $this->item->paginationposition && !$this->item->paginationrelative):
        echo $this->item->pagination;
    ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (isset($urls) && ((!empty($urls->urls_position) && ($urls->urls_position == '1')) || ($params->get('urls_position') == '1'))) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('links'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php // Optional teaser intro text for guests ?>
    <?php elseif ($params->get('show_noauth') == true && $user->get('guest')) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>
    <?php // Optional link to let them register to see the whole article. ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('show_readmore') && $this->item->fulltext != null) : ?>
    <?php $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu(); ?>
    <?php $active = $menu->getActive(); ?>
    <?php $itemId = $active->id; ?>
    <?php $link = new JUri(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&Itemid=' . $itemId, false)); ?>
    <?php $link->setVar('return', base64_encode(JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid, $this->item->language), false))); ?>
    <p class="readmore">
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="register">
        <?php $attribs = json_decode($this->item->attribs); ?>
        <?php
        if ($attribs->alternative_readmore == null) :
            echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_REGISTER_TO_READ_MORE');
        elseif ($readmore = $this->item->alternative_readmore) :
            echo $readmore;
            if ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) != 0) :
                echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
            endif;
        elseif ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) == 0) :
            echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE_TITLE');
        else :
            echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE');
            echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
        endif; ?>
        </a>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && $this->item->paginationposition && $this->item->paginationrelative) :
        echo $this->item->pagination;
    ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayContent; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just select the option to hide details? This is available when you create articles, but generally I change it globally to hide everything. (Click on option in the article manager).

Comment: @Elin Then how would you show "By John Doe, on November 4, 2015" ? The goal is not to remove details totally, but to customize it...

Comment: I would set author to show, date published to show, everything else to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS ***and*** Language overrides worked out.

CSS : display:none to get rid of unwanted stuff and display:inline-block to put everything in a single line.

Changing Words in Joomla 3.4 backend :

- from the control panel, click on Languages in the sidebar menu
- Click 'overrides'
- Choose the language in 'filter'
- Click 'new'
- in the form field next to 'search' button, type in the text you want to change
- select the right string variable
- Type in the wanted text
- Save

done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the above by CSS - but sometimes it's a bit tricky, so you will need to change the override file. You can do that by changing the file `/templates/your-template/html/com_content/article/default.php`

If you can't find that file (or that directory structure), then you will need to copy the this file `components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php` to `/templates/your-template/html/com_content/article/default.php` (if there is a directory that doesn't exist then you will need to create it. for example, if you can only find the `/templates/your-template/html` under your `templates` folder the you will need to create the `com_content` folder under the `html` folder and then the `article` folder under the `com_content` folder).

You can then modify the `default.php` file to change the layout. Make sure you clear your Joomla cache to see your changes.

Comment: Great, that's clear about the "Where"... I don't read PHP, but I can't identify none of the words "details" or "written"...It seems to be hidden in variables. 

Thanks for helping decrypt this.